# SciFi movie - US town where aliens have infiltrated and control humans through a corporation

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

US town where aliens have infiltrated and control humans through a corporation.

I think this might be an early to mid eighties movie (possibly TV movie).  All the humans work for the Corporation in what seems an idyllic town.  One family discover their intentions and I seem to remember the end of the film was possibly underground?  I had thought one of the aliens was played by Sarah Douglas (from Superman 2) but no film in her credits seem to match this.

Comment: Did the aliens have backward-bending knees?  The underground setting reminds me of [*The Arrival*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Arrival_(1996_film)) (1996).

Comment: Thanks but no, this film was much earlier.  80's I am sure but possibly late 70's at a push

Comment: This description reminds me pretty strongly of Alien Prey by John Peel, but that’s a book and not a movie and the timings off, I think